# Word for brands becoming lexicon

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

What is the word for popular brands becoming nouns in common lexicon? For example, Kleenex, Xerox, q-tips etc

Comment: No references, and I'm not certain this isn't itself a neologism, but "genericization" is a word I've often seen used for this phenomenon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are instances of **trademark genericization**.

> A generic trademark, also known as a genericized trademark or proprietary eponym, is a trademark or brand name that, due to its popularity and/or significance, has become the generic name for, or synonymous with, a general class of product or service, usually against the intentions of the trademark's holder.

([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_trademark))